# Update interval value for continuous GPS location

Tags: blackberry, gps, location, location-provider

I am working on a BlackBerry Application that is supposed to update the location at fixed intervals. The interval value can be selected/changed from a slider. It varies between 1 minute, 2 minutes, 5 minutes, 30 minutes etc. On the very first load (Start App), location interval is 30 seconds. After this, I store the slider value in a persistent store and location is updated accordingly with the set interval. Background thread running to update location is as follows:

```java
private boolean startLocationUpdate()
{
    boolean retval = false;
    try
    {
        LocationProvider locationProvider = LocationProvider.getInstance(null);
        if ( locationProvider == null )
        {
            Runnable showGpsUnsupportedDialog = new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    Dialog.alert("GPS is not supported on this platform, exiting...");
                    //System.exit( 1 );
                }
            };
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeAndWait( showGpsUnsupportedDialog ); // Ask event-dispatcher thread to display dialog ASAP.
        }
        else
        {
            locationProvider.setLocationListener(new LocationListenerImpl(), interval, -1, -1);
            retval = true;
        }
    }
    catch (LocationException le)
    {
        System.err.println("Failed to instantiate the LocationProvider object, exiting...");
        System.err.println(le);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return retval;
}

private class LocationListenerImpl implements LocationListener
{
    public void locationUpdated(LocationProvider provider, Location location)
    {
        if(location.isValid())
        {
            double longitude = location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLongitude();
            double latitude = location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude();
            updateLocationScreen(latitude, longitude);
        }
    }
    public void providerStateChanged(LocationProvider provider, int newState)
    {
    }
}

private void updateLocationScreen(final double latitude, final double longitude)
{
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            double lat = latitude;
            double longi = longitude;
            lblLatitude.setText(Double.toString(lat));
            spacing.setText(", ");
            lblLongitude.setText(Double.toString(longi));
        }
    });
}
```

Along with this, there is a "Refresh" button available that will start acquiring a location update immediately once clicked. This button calls a method is another class to acquire the location. The method is as follows:

```java
try {
    Criteria myCriteria = new Criteria();
    myCriteria.setCostAllowed(false);
    LocationProvider myLocationProvider = LocationProvider.getInstance(myCriteria);
    double heading = 0;
    double velocity = 0;

    try {
        Location myLocation = myLocationProvider.getLocation(6000);
        if(myLocation.isValid())
        {
            double longitude = myLocation.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLongitude();
            double latitude = myLocation.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude();
        }
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //Dialog.alert("Location Updated");
            }
        });
        setLocation(myLocation.getQualifiedCoordinates(),velocity,heading);
    } catch ( InterruptedException iex ) {
        System.out.println(iex.getMessage());
    } catch ( LocationException lex ) {
        System.out.println(lex.getMessage());
    }
} catch ( LocationException lex ) {
    System.out.println(lex.getMessage());
}
```

Problems I am facing:

**1)** Interval value not changing. I am implementing the change by picking the value from the persistent store as:

```java
if (PersistentStoreHelper.persistentHashtable.containsKey("gpsInterval"))
{
    String intervalValue=((String) PersistentStoreHelper.persistentHashtable.get("gpsInterval"));
    MyScreen.interval=Integer.parseInt(intervalValue);
}
```

This is never empty as navigation to this page inserts a value of 30 minutes to it.

**2)** Once the "Refresh" button is clicked, the background thread seems to be cancelled. It no longer runs at any interval value.

I read that there is only one instance of the location provider created and with "Refresh" it is cancelled after acquiring the location and thus the background thread stops. **Is this true?** If yes, how can I achieve my desired result.

EDIT: The gpsInterval value is read as follows:

```java
if (PersistentStoreHelper.persistentHashtable.containsKey("gpsInterval"))
{
    String intervalValue=((String)PersistentStoreHelper.persistentHashtable.get("gpsInterval"));
    interval=Integer.parseInt(intervalValue);
}
else
{
    interval=10;
}
```

Comment: A couple questions: 1) are you sure that you are properly saving the `gpsInterval` to the persistent store?  You don't show that code, only the code that reads it.  Maybe you're not calling `commit()` on the store?  2) you show the code that sets `MyScreen.interval` to a new value.  but just setting that value by itself won't change anything.  from what I see, that value is used in the `startLocationUpdate()` method.  are you making sure to call `startLocationUpdate()` again, after the user changes the interval with their slider?

Comment: @Nate thanks for the reply. 1)Yes I am sure the value is being saved as I can see it while debugging.I have edited my question to include code I am using to read the value. I am not calling commit() though. Where should this be called? 2) I am not calling the startLocationUpdate() method again. My assumption is that the startLocationUpdate() thread is always running in the background at the selected interval. Is this not so? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Saving the Interval

So, first of all, make sure that when you let the user **change** the update interval, via the slider, you properly save it to the `PersistentStore`.  The code should look something like this:

```java
// NOTE: I would recommend persisting the slider value as an Integer, not a String,
//   but, the original code used String, so that's what this uses
hashtable.put("gpsInterval", (new Integer(intervalSlider.getValue())).toString());
PersistentObject po = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(APP_BUNDLE_ID);
po.setContents(hashtable);
po.commit();
```

Since you didn't post that code, I just wanted to be sure that it was being saved to the persistent store correctly.

### Updating the Location Provider / Listener

The other issue, that **is** a problem, is that you kick off the location updates in `startLocationUpdate()` with this code:

```java
locationProvider.setLocationListener(new LocationListenerImpl(), interval, -1, -1);
```

That uses the value of the `interval` variable **at the instant that `setLocationListener()` is called**.  If you later update the `interval` variable,

```java
String intervalValue=((String) PersistentStoreHelper.persistentHashtable.get("gpsInterval"));
MyScreen.interval=Integer.parseInt(intervalValue);
```

this will have no effect on the location listener.  It will keep updating with the *original* interval value, not the new one.  You would have to call `setLocationListener()` again, with the new value of `interval`.  With your code, you should probably just call `startLocationUpdate()` again:

```java
String intervalValue=((String) PersistentStoreHelper.persistentHashtable.get("gpsInterval"));
MyScreen.interval=Integer.parseInt(intervalValue);
startLocationUpdate();
```

### Refresh Problem

I'm not 100% sure, but my guess would be that in your existing code that's used when the **Refresh** button is pressed, you are **changing** to a different `LocationProvider` with different *criteria*.  That's probably why the first one is cancelled.

Try changing your `startLocationUpdate()` method to **save** the provider as a member variable:

```java
/** this is the one location provider used by this class! */
private LocationProvider _locationProvider;

private boolean startLocationUpdate()
{
    boolean retval = false;
    try
    {
        _locationProvider = LocationProvider.getInstance(null);
```

then, in your refresh code, use the **same** location provider to get the current location:

```java
double heading = 0;
double velocity = 0;

try {
    Location myLocation = _locationProvider.getLocation(6000);
    if(myLocation.isValid())
```

**Note:** if you really do want to `setCostAllowed(false)`, that's fine.  Do that the *first* time that you assign the `_locationProvider` member variable.  And use that provider/criteria both for normal periodic location updates, and your **Refresh** button handler.  I think the key is to use the same provider, not create a new one with different criteria.

Comment: Thanks @Nate, quite a detailed answer. Considering I call another method, for instance, startLocationUpdate1() instead of startLocationUpdate() where I provide the new interval, will this call cancel the old StartLocaionUpdate()? Something like the Refresh button which cancels the other LocationProvider...

Comment: @Sarah, Yes, if you read the documentation on `setLocationListener()` you see that setting a listener removes the old one (which might have a different *interval*).  So, if you have another method that calls `setLocationListener()` again, that should work.  I would still recommend not having `setLocationUpdate()` and `setLocationUpdate1()`.  Just make one method that takes `(int updateInterval)` as a parameter.